# Solving system of coupled differential equations using scipy odeint

Tags: python, scipy

I am a bit confused with `odeint`.

I found one example below to solve `y"=ay + by'`. So it seems that `y[0]` is the function, `y[1]` is the first derivative.

So does the following expression mean `y[1] =y'` and `y'[1]= a*y[0]+b*y[1]` ?

If it were  `y[2], a*y[0]+b*y[1]`, what would it mean?

I am a bit confused since the expression does not say the left hand side of the equation.

I also encountered expressions like `[a(y[0], y[1]), b(y[0], y[1])]` but have no clue of the differential equation.

Here is one example:

```
from scipy.integrate import odeint
from pylab import * # for plotting commands

def deriv(y,t): # return derivatives of the array y
    a = -2.0
    b = -0.1
    return array([ y[1], a*y[0]+b*y[1] ])

time = linspace(0.0,10.0,1000)
yinit = array([0.0005,0.2]) # initial values
y = odeint(deriv,yinit,time)
figure()
plot(time,y[:,0])
xlabel('t')
ylabel('y')
show()
```

Comment: I found the answer, the equations should be represented in the following way: y1'= y2 , y2'=y3, .., yn'=F(x,..) and only right hand sides of the equations have to be given for solving the differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use `Y` in `deriv` instead of `y` for the rest of answer to be clear:

```
def deriv(Y,t): # return derivatives of the array Y
    a = -2.0
    b = -0.1
    return array([ Y[1], a*Y[0]+b*Y[1] ])
```

Function `deriv` takes `Y = [y, y']` as the input.

And it should output their derivatives (`[y', y'']`).

`y' = Y[1]`

`y'' = a*Y[0]+b*Y[1]`

Answer (score 1):

Read the documentation on [odeint](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html). It requires as an input equation of the following sort:

> dy/dt = func(y,t0,...)

As far as I understand it, first element of `array([ y[1], a*y[0]+b*y[1] ])`, i.e. `y[1]` is put as `y` in  `dy/dt` which gives `dy[1]/dt = y[2]`. The second element, i.e. `a*y[0]+b*y[1]` serves as `func(y,t0,...)`