# 2'nd order ode python - cfd - sphere motion in fluid flow

Tags: python, motion, ode

phisical problem is given by 2'nd order ODE: m*x''= s*(v - x')^2
mathematical solution is rewriting to 2x 1'nd order ODE: u = x' , u' = s(v - u)^2

boundary conditions: u0 = 0, x0 = 0

t0=0, tmax=10., dt=1.

but i think theres some bug, and cant find it

code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import pylab as pl

rho=10e3
Cd=1
r=0.05
m=5
s=rho*Cd*(r**2)*np.pi/(2*m)
v=1

t_max, dt = 10., 1.
time_vec = np.linspace(0, t_max, num=np.round(t_max/dt)+1)
x_vec=[0.,0.]

def d(x_vec,t):
    return np.array([s*((v-x_vec[0])**2), x_vec[0]]) # u'[0]=s*((v-u_vec[0])**2), u[1]'=u_vec[0]

x,u = odeint(func=d, y0=x_vec, t=time_vec).T

pl.plot(time_vec, u[:], label='u[m/s]=x/t')
pl.plot(time_vec, x[:], label="x[m]")
pl.legend()
pl.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like you may want to use x and u instead of u and u'.  See examples [here (page 2)](http://bulldog2.redlands.edu/facultyfolder/deweerd/tutorials/Tutorial-ODEs.pdf) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9165113/2877364) and also odeint docs.  With the system `x'=u` and `u' = s(v - u)^2`, `d` can take `[x,u]` as input and return `[x',u']` as `odeint` expects.